# Is there a way to update federalHoliday function in tis package v1.38 in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to update the federalHolidays funciton in tis v1.38? It seems to omit US Independence Day. I'm using the code below in R version 3.63

```
library(tis)
library(timeDate)
isHoliday("2020-07-04")
federalHolidays(getRmetricsOption("currentYear"))
```

I get the following output:

```
> isHoliday("2020-07-04")
[1] FALSE

> federalHolidays(2020)
NewYears       MLKing   GWBirthday     Memorial        Labor     Columbus     Veterans Thanksgiving    Christmas 
20200101     20200120     20200217     20200525     20200907     20201012     20201111     20201126     20201225
```

Comment: If you have an issue with functions internal to a package, it's better to contact the authors rather than post here. However, you can just add the argument `businessOnly = F` or `board = T` to include Independence Day. By default the function excludes holidays on weekends. Read the documentation using `?federalHolidays` to better understand the function.

Comment: @caldwellst thank you! I didn't realize holidays on weekends were exluded.